# Suddenly it does not deploy to heroku in C9 ,Django

Tags: django, git, heroku

Only 30 minutes before it was running normally.

I am developing on c9.

There are three commands I use to deploy.

```
git add .
git commit -m'a'
git push heroku master
```

I've been deploying with these three commands, and an error occurred at some point.

```
2017-11-22T14:13:32.376772+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found
2017-11-22T14:13:32.462690+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-11-22T14:13:33.756325+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=quiet-tundra-61346.herokuapp.com request_id=964a2694-e6c3-41c6-8357-4d5aa1ae70e6 fwd="175.193.51.62" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I was so embarrassed because I had no problems for 10 days.

When I looked at the difference, it was different from the previous one when pushing heroku.

```
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 59.2M
```

Previously, the figure was clearly above 70 meters.

On c9, it runs without any problems.

The modified code is also veiw.py logic.

I commented out that part, but the same result came out.

I do not even know where to get the code because I do not know which part is the problem. Can not you find out with this information?

I've written git commit -m'q in the middle, and is this a problem?

Comment: Can you show what your `Procfile` and `requirements.txt` files look like?